# Avoiding duplications when comparing array elements

Tags: algorithm, c++11, compare

The question is something like: Go through an array and find pairs of elements that add up to a certain sum k.

```
for (auto i : array) {
   for (auto j : array) {
        if (i+j==k) {
            *Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Say we had `array = [1,2,5]` and `k=3; when i=1 and j=2`, we would execute the *Do something*. But when `i=2` and `j=1`, we would execute *Do something* again, even though we have already found 2 elements and we would be repeating the answer.

Essentially, how can one go through an array and avoid comparing the same 2 elements multiple times?

Comment: Start by sorting the vector...

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter, then decide which half of all pairs you want: the one where `i >= j`, or the one where `i <= j`.

```
for (i=0...)
    for (j=i...)
```

---

Like rici commented, this is a very slow (`O(N^2)`) algorithm compared to sorting (a copy of) the vector.  I think then you could iterate `i` forwards from the start, and `j` backwards from the end, comparing `i+j <= k` to decide whether to modify `i` or `j` next.

Answer (score 0):

If I am *not* getting your question wrong then this explained procedure could be a way to solve it.

1. Sort your array in **increasing** order *( Preferably **merge** sort because it takes **O(n.log(n))**  time )*.
2. Now, take two indices let call them **low** and **high**, where low is index to the **left-most smallest** number of the sorted array and high is index to the **right-most largest** number of the same sorted array.
3. Now, do like this :

   ```
   while(low < high) {
       if(arr[low] + arr[high] == k) {
           print "unique pair found"
           high = high - 1;
           low = low + 1;
       }

       else if(arr[low] + arr[high] > k){
           high = high - 1;    
       } 

       else {
           low = low + 1;
       }
   }
   ```
4. It's time complexity is O(n), it will definitely give what you are looking for ? (Any **doubt** most welcome).

Answer (score -1):

You could put the results of `i + j` in a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), then [sort it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and then [remove duplicates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique), and finally go over the vector and "do something".

Comment: Sorting all combinations of `array[i] + array[j]` would be slower than just looping over `array` a bunch of times.  Or are you intentionally just giving a hint on the assumption this is a homework question, to get the OP thinking of at least a bad way to solve the problem?